# Datalist putting wrong value in ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, html-datalist

I am using Angular 1.6

I have a a `text input` which is connected to a `datalist`.

The `datalist` options are populated through `ng-repeat`. The `value` is an "id" but what is displayed is a "name".

The `text input` is connected to an `ng-model`.

The problem is, when I choose an option from the datalist, it overrides the "name" with the "id". As that is the value.

**I need to save the value, but display and be able to edit the name.**

This is the example code:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function() {
    const vm=this;
    vm.people=[{id:1,name:"Bob"},{id:2,name:"Jane"},{id:3,name:"Don"},
               {id:4,name:"Eric"},{id:5,name:"Sally"}];
});
```

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <pre>{{vm.myName|json}}</pre>
    <label>
        <span>My Name!</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" list="names" ng-model="vm.myName" />
        <datalist id="names">
            <option ng-repeat="person in vm.people" value="{{:: person.id}}">
              {{:: person.name}}
            </option>
        </datalist>
    </label>
</div>
```

One solution is I could hook up an `ng-change` to the `input` and then in the `controller` run a filter function, which would look like:

```
// in JS (excerpt)
vm.updateMyName = name => {
    vm.myName = vm.people.filter(n => n.name === name)[0].id
};
```

```
<!-- in html (excerpt) -->
<input type="text" name="name" list="names" ng-model="vm.throwAwayValue"
       ng-change="vm.updateMyName(vm.throwAwayValue)" />
<datalist id="names">
    <option ng-repeat="person in vm.people">
      {{:: person.name}}
    </option>
</datalist>
```

However I'm screwed if there are duplicate names, as it would match the id of that first name (I won't get into that it anyways wouldn't be user-friendly to have a drop-down list with duplicate options). And it also seems like quite a bit of unnecessary boilerplate.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to combine the two fields of the object:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <pre>{{vm.myName|json}}</pre>
    <label>
        <span>My Name!</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" list="names" ng-model="vm.myName" />
        <datalist id="names">
            <option ng-repeat="person in vm.people" 
                value="{{person.id +' '+ person.name}}" >
            </option>
        </datalist>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) because it supports storing an object as the value while only displaying a certain property as the option. Using `md-select` and `md-option` will allow you to store your `person` variable as the `value`, while only displaying `person.name` as what is displayed in the options dropdown.